# How to disable additivity on marker logger?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I have defined a `Marker` and would like to log this only to a specific file. Therefore I'm trying to set `additivity = false`. But it does not work and is still also logged to my global logfile in addition. What might be wrong here?

```
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="TEST" fileName="test.log" filePattern="test1.log">
            <MarkerFilter marker="TEST_LOG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="GLOBAL" fileName="global.log" filePattern="global.log">
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="TEST_LOG" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <logger name="foo" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="TEST" />
        </logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

usage:

```
LogManager.getRootLogger().info(MarkerManager.getMarker("TEST_LOG"), "test log");
```

Comment: Don't you need to add a `name` to your `logger` element?

Comment: I also tried adding a name, updated my post above, but same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additivity is not going to work in your case, coz additivity is controlling a specific logger not to inherit parent's appender.

In your config, you are setting logger `foo` to have `additivity` = false, which means, unless you are using `foo` or its children loggers for your logging, you will still follow root loggers' config.  (I can't see your root logger config in your post, I suspect it is referring to both appenders).  From your quoted code, you are using the root logger for your logging, the configuration of `foo` logger simply won't take effect.

There are two solution I can suggest:

1. For all log messages you log with `TEST_LOG` marker, make sure you log it using `foo` logger. or,
2. If you need to use any logger for your `TEST_LOG` messages, then you should reconfigure your appender, so that your `GLOBAL` file appender accept anything BUT `TEST_LOG`.  (Currently you are only denying `SELL_FAILURE` marker)

Correct solution depends on your actual requirement.  Make sure you understand the basic concepts so you can choose the right solution for you.

---

Edit:

First, even with your "correct" config you mentioned in the comment, the issue of different loggers still holds.  Which mean, coz you are using root logger to do your logging, your config for `foo` logger has nothing to do with your log message, and additivity is out of picture in your case.

I am not using Log4J2, a brief check on the usage of filter lead me to two issues:

First, I believe proper way to define more than 1 filter is to make use of Composite Filter (which means defining in a `<Filters>` element, though I don't quite get the syntax from Log4J's doc).

Second, even you define it in composite filter, your config will still have problem.  When a log event is having INFO or higher level, you declare in filter it is an `ACCEPT` or `DENY` which will prohibit subsequent filter evaluation.  If you want to log messages with `INFO` and not containing `TEST_LOG` marker, you should do something like:

```
<MarkerFilter marker="TEST_LOG" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NETURAL"/>
<ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
```

`NEUTRAL` means current filter cannot determine whether to accept or deny the message, and will evaluate next filter to determine it.

Comment: Sorry, that `SELL_FAILURE` was copypast issue. Indeed I already wrote `TEST_LOG` there to deny anything BUT this marker. Though, it still gets logged to root...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Configuring the logging as you wrote above does exactly work as expected! So indeed what I did not know is that Filter order is important here.

Comment: In fact it is not only the order is important, but you need to also know that, once a filter decide whether to "accept" or "deny" a log event, no subsequent filter evaluation will happen.  "NEUTRAL" is the key here

Answer (score 2):

In the sample code the marker is named `"TEST"`, but in the configuration the MarkerFilter only accepts log events with marker `"TEST_LOG"`. Config and code should use the same string.

In addition, you probably need to define two Appenders: one for your global log file and one for your specific (marked) log events. Then ACCEPT the marked log events only in your specific appender, and DENY the marked log events in the global appender.

Comment: Sorry, the marker name was a typo. I of course have a 2nd appender already that creates my global log file. I addet the following marker filter to it `<MarkerFilter marker="SELL_FAILURE" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>`, but still I see the marker logging in the global file

Comment: In that case, can you please post your full log4j2.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things I noticed:

- You should use the same marker string in the code, and in the config for *both* MarkerFilters.
- You need to add AppenderRef elements to connect your logger to both appenders
- You can specify a level in the AppenderRef, this is easier than using a ThresholdFilter

Which gives you this config:

```
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="MARKED_ONLY" fileName="markedOnly.log" filePattern="markedOnly1.log">
            <MarkerFilter marker="MY_MARKER" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="GLOBAL" fileName="global.log" filePattern="global.log">
            <MarkerFilter marker="MY_MARKER" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <root level="trace">
            <appender-ref ref="MARKED_ONLY" level="trace" />
            <appender-ref ref="GLOBAL" level="info" />
        </root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And this code:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class); // or .getRootLogger()
logger.info(MarkerManager.getMarker("MY_MARKER"), "test log");
```

Note it is important to use the same "MY_MARKER" string in the code, and in the filters for both appenders. That way, the appender for the global file can use that filter to DENY the marked log events.